# Applying Unsharp Mask on RGB Images?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, filtering, convolution

Is the Unsharp mask algorithm the same for RGB images as for grayscale?
Do I just apply it to all channels?

Or maybe I could convert RGB -> HSL and apply it, then go back to RGB?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a super noob in this area, but surely you need to adjust your algorithm based on sensor sensitivity to the different wavelengths if you're gonna use all 3 channels?

Comment: From the Wikipedia article, it is said that GIMP and Photoshop just subtract a Gaussian-blurred version of the image from the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the online [GIMP documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-unsharp-mask.html):

> **To prevent color distortion while sharpening, Decompose your image to HSV and work only on Value. Then Compose the image to HSV.** Go to
>   Colors → Components → Decompose.... Make sure the Decompose to Layers
>   box is checked. Choose HSV and click OK. You will get a new grey-level
>   image with three layers, one for Hue, one for Saturation, and one for
>   Value. (Close the original image so you won't get confused). Select
>   the Value layer and apply your sharpening to it. When you are done,
>   with that same layer selected, reverse the process. Go to Colors →
>   Components → Compose.... Again choose HSV and click OK. You will get
>   back your original image except that it will have been sharpened in
>   the Value component.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you that the big photo editing applications you're used to do it exactly that way - they apply the unsharp mask filter to each color channel independently.